# contract-deployment

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Reference link: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html#simple-smart-contract

Why it returns 0, instead of 100?

[image: greeter.get() returns 0 instead of 100, any help??]

Answer (score 3):

You are passing `x = 100` to the contract constructor in your console session, but there is no constructor in the contract.

Here is your code:

```
var greeter1 = greeterContract.new(x, {from: ...
```

First argument `x` is considered as a contract constructor argument. See web3 API [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) for more info.

Try these steps instead:

```
var greeter1 = greeterContract.new({from: web3.eth.accounts[0], data: code, gas: 1000000})
```

Send transaction that calls `set` function on the new contract instance:

```
greeter1.set(100)
```

Call `get` function without sending transaction:

```
greeter1.get.call()
```

Please note the difference: the first command creates a transaction but the second does not.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided screen you are setting **local JavaScript variable in the console** to 100.

Then you are asking the contract for its variable **storedData**.

No call to **SimpleStorage.set()** has been made in this point, so the contract returns the default uninitialized value that is 0.

Comment: Tq for the theoritical explanation , pl provide practical explanation

Comment: @NarraVasu: Let's go back to the basics. Do you know the concept of a variable in the programming language and how they work?

Answer (score 1):

1. simplestorage_sol_simplestorage.set(100)
2. if there is error msg shows 'invalid address'
   then eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]
3. simplestorage_sol_simplestorage.set(100)
4. simplestorage_sol_simplestorage.get()

[image]

Comment: what is simplestorage_sol_simplestorage ? is it compiled code of solc compiler . In my contract on geth console simplestorage_sol_simplestorage compiled code not showing like above . any suggestion?

Comment: simplestorage_sol_simplestorage is the name of the contract instance name, equals to 'greeter1' in your example.

Comment: Thank you for screenshot , but i might fail at last step at set() value can you provide whole contract screen shot if possible . Thank you